# Is (0,0) of $V(x-y^2)$ a smooth point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I'm pretty sure it is a smooth point since given $f(x,y)=x-y^2$ the gradient $df=(1,-2y)$ is always non-singular. I'm asking because page 22 of [Principle of Algebraic Geometry](http://books.google.com/books?id=Sny48qKdW40C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) says:

```
Note that p is a smooth point of V if and only if mult_p(V)=1.
```

The multiplicity is defined to be the sheets of the covering map induced by the variety around p. Since 0 is a multiple root of $y^2$, (0,0) is a branch point of Riemann surface defined by $f$, so any neighborhood of (0,0) will have 2 sheets, which means (0,0) is singular based on the above statement.
What's wrong here?

Comment: 0 is a multiple root of $y^2$, but $(0,0)$ is not a multiple root of $x-y^2$.

Comment: Another way to see it is smooth is to note that the map $k[x, y]/(x - y^{2}) \rightarrow k[y]$ given by $x \mapsto y^{2}, y \mapsto y$ is an isomorphism. Hence, the variety you are looking at is isomorphic to affine 1 space.

Comment: I realized that the projection should be done to a generic plane which won't lead to a 2 sheets covering in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented on by KReiser, $x-y^2$ does not have multiplicity $2$ at the origin. There is a complicated algebraic way of defining multiplicity (see the entire book *Algebre Locale Multiplicities* by Serre).

Intuitively, one can get at the multiplicity geometrically though. In our tame case, you can get the multiplicity of $x-y^2$ at $(0,0)$ by testing its intersections against lines. In particular, consider the line $\ell=\{y=0\}$. Then, the intersection of $\ell$ and $V(x-y^2)$ has multiplicity $1$ at $(0,0)$.

This multiplicity is calculated as

$$\ell_{k[x,y]_{(x,y)}} \,\,k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(x-y^2,y)=1$$